# Accessing RStudio server on Cloudera VM running on Ubuntu Host

Tags: hadoop, rstudio, cloudera, rhadoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

What I would like to do:
Access RStudio WebGUI, running on a Cloudera Quickstart VM on an Ubuntu Host from a OSX Browser.

This is what works:
 1. Ubuntu host is running Cloudera Quickstart VM
 2. Cloudera VM has R and RStudio Server installed and running. The WebGUI is accessible from the Cloudera VM.

What I cannot:
I cannot access my WebGUI from my OSX Browser. It just times out.

Funny thing is, that I can access Cloudera Manager on VM on the Host IP with a port, but I cannot access the RStudio Server on the VM via the same IP. Any clues to where I should start?

Comment: I found that adding the port forwarding in the Virtualbox network adapter solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the port forwarding in the Virtualbox network adapter solved my problem.

1. Settings for Virtual Machine
2. Choose Network Adapter that has NAT
3. Add the port for RStudio Server - 8787 in the port forwarding.

There you have it :)